# skipping exceptions in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I am running a large, diverse dataset through a java program that imports data from an old schema, transforms it, and then inserts the data into a new schema.  The program was successfully tested on pilot data, but is throwing exceptions on real world data.

***I want to be able to count how many exceptions are thrown by the entire dataset, and to log which records are throwing the exceptions.  Can someone show me how to do this?***

As it stands, the program is currently crashing when it hits the first exception, so I have no idea whether there will be one exception or 1,000 exceptions if the code were able to progress all the way through the dataset.

I am enclosing relevant aspects of my code below.  How do I change it so that it skips exceptions while noting their count and ClientNumber?

```
try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection sourceConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:source_db");
    Statement st = sourceConn.createStatement();
    Connection destinationConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:destination_db");

    int ClientNumber;
    String Name;
    ResultSet rest = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sourceTable");
    PreparedStatement ps5 = null;
    PreparedStatement ps6 = null;
    PreparedStatement ps7 = null;
    PreparedStatement ps8 = null;
    while(rest.next()){
        ClientNumber = rest.getInt(1);
        Name = rest.getString(2);//plus other variables skipped here for brevity
        ps5 = destinationConn.prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO Clients ("
            + "ClientNumber, Name) "
            +"VALUES (?, ?)"
            );
        ps5.setInt(1, ClientNumber);
        ps5.setString(2, Name);
        ps5.executeUpdate();
        //some other stuff for ps6,ps7,ps8
        destinationConn.commit();
    }
    //ps5.close();
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe){cnfe.printStackTrace();}
catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: Put the ``catch`` blocks for the ``SQLException`` more close to the part where the exception actually occurs (you do not mention that, but I guess inside the loop).

Comment: @qqilihq Thank you.  I am in the process of doing that for what is actually a huge amount of code, which means many try catch blocks.  The while(rest.next) block is asking for its own try catch block, rather than let me create several try catch blocks within it. Can you suggest a way that I can change the while definition so that I can divide its components into several try catch blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this, just write the loop differently:

```
try {
    // TODO: write your setup code here

    boolean hasNext = false;
    try {
        hasNext = rest.next();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: log exception, increase a counter
    }
    while(hasNext){
        try {
            // TODO: write your processing code here

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: log exception, increase a counter
        }
        try {
            hasNext = rest.next();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: log exception, increase a counter
            hasNext = false; //prevent infinite loops
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    // TODO: this should never happen, handle ClassNotFoundException etc.
}
```

Update: we can get rid of having to call next() twice, like this:

```
try {
    // TODO: write your setup code here

    while(true){
        try {
            if(!rest.next()){
                break;
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: log exception, increase a counter
            break;
        }
        try {
            // TODO: write your processing code here

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: log exception, increase a counter
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    // TODO: this should never happen, handle ClassNotFoundException etc.
}
```

Comment: I am done integrating your suggestions.  I am marking yours as the answer and giving +1 because creating the Boolean hasNext variable was very helpful.  I ended up creating a separate try catch block for every line of code that operates on rest, which made all the difference.  However, that became more feasible after using your hasNext Boolean variable.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a second version which gets rid of having to call next() twice, and also doesn't need the hasNext anymore.

Comment: Is there any reason why it is bad to call next() twice?

Answer (score 1):

Below code gives you a hint. Printing ClientNumber when an error occurs depends on what exactly you want to print. But you can add another log inside the inner catch. I deliberately used exception instead of SQLException because the exception you get may have been any kind of exception which you haven't mentioned in your post

```
try {
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection sourceConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:source_db");
Statement st = sourceConn.createStatement();
Connection destinationConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:destination_db");

int ClientNumber;
int errCounter = 0; 
String Name;
ResultSet rest = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sourceTable");
PreparedStatement ps5 = null;
PreparedStatement ps6 = null;
PreparedStatement ps7 = null;
PreparedStatement ps8 = null;
while(rest.next()){
    try {
    ClientNumber = rest.getInt(1);
    Name = rest.getString(2);//plus other variables skipped here for brevity
    ps5 = destinationConn.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO Clients ("
        + "ClientNumber, Name) "
        +"VALUES (?, ?)"
        );
    ps5.setInt(1, ClientNumber);
    ps5.setString(2, Name);
    ps5.executeUpdate();
    //some other stuff for ps6,ps7,ps8
    destinationConn.commit();
    }catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      errCounter++;
    }
} //end while
 if(errCounter > 0) 
   System.out.println(String.format("Error occured %d times", errCounter));

} catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
    cnfe.printStackTrace();}     
}
```

Comment: +1 for trying to help.  I ended up using a different approach to solve the problem.  However, your counting idea is helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome. Your application seems to be doing a classic migration or ETL job. You are skipping certain records which are not processable probably because of incompatibility or because of poor input data quality. **Spring Batch framework** tries to offer some out of the box approaches to take care of these kind of issues such as skipping, chunk read and write etc.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look into Spring Batch Framework.  I use other Spring tools, and it would be nice to use Spring for everything.